# Tensorflow tutorial on MNIST

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) Tensorflow tutorial loads an already existing dataset (MNIST) into the code. Instead of that I want to insert my own training and testing images.

```
def main(unused_argv):
# Load training and eval data
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
train_data = mnist.train.images # Returns np.array      
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
eval_data = mnist.test.images # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

It says it returns an np array of raw pixel values.

My question:

**1. How do I create such a numpy array for my own image set?**
I want to do this so I can directly substitute my numpy array instead of this MNIST data in the sample code and train the model on my data (0-9 and A-Z).

**EDIT:** On further analysis, I've realized that the pixel values in `mnist.train.images` and `mnist.test.images` have been normalized between 0 to 1 from 0 to 255 ( I suppose)  How does this normalization help?

Folder structure: Training and testing folder are in the same folder

```
Training folder:
--> 0
    -->Image_Of_0.png
--> 1
    -->Image_Of_1.png
.
.
.
--> Z
    -->Image_Of_Z.png

Testing folder:
--> 0
    -->Image_Of_0.png
--> 1
    -->Image_Of_1.png
.
.
.
--> Z
    -->Image_Of_Z.png
```

Code I wrote:

```
Names = [['C:\\Users\\xx\\Project\\training-images', 'train',9490], ['C:\\Users\\xx\\Project\\test-images', 'test',3175]]

#9490 is the number of training files in total (All the PNGs)
#3175 is the number of testing files in total (All the PNGs)
for name in Names:
FileList = []
for dirname in os.listdir(name[0]):
    path = os.path.join(name[0], dirname)
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            FileList.append(os.path.join(name[0], dirname, filename))
print(FileList) 


## Creates list of all PNG files in training and testing folder

x_data = np.array([np.array(cv2.imread(filename)) for filename in FileList])
pixels = x_data.flatten().reshape(name[2], 2352)   #2352 = 28 * 28 * 3 image
print(pixels)
```

Can the pixels array created be supplied as the training and testing data i.e would it have the same format as the data being supplied in the sample code?

**2. Similarly what numpy array must be created for all the labels? (Folder names)**

Answer (score 0):

*1. How do I create such a numpy array for my own image set?*

TensorFlow accepts data in multiple ways (tf.data, feed_dict, QueueRunner).
What you should be using is TFRecord which is accessible via tf.data API. It is also [recommended format](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data). Lets say you have folder containing images and you want to convert it to tfrecord file.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np
import glob
from PIL import Image

# Converting the values into features
# _int64 is used for numeric values

def _int64_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

# _bytes is used for string/char values

def _bytes_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
tfrecord_filename = 'something.tfrecords'

# Initiating the writer and creating the tfrecords file.

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_filename)

# Loading the location of all files - image dataset
# Considering our image dataset has apple or orange
# The images are named as apple01.jpg, apple02.jpg .. , orange01.jpg .. etc.

images = glob.glob('data/*.jpg')
for image in images[:1]:
  img = Image.open(image)
  img = np.array(img.resize((32,32)))
label = 0 if 'apple' in image else 1
feature = { 'label': _int64_feature(label),
              'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()) }

#create an example protocol buffer
 example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

#writing the serialized example.
 writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Now to read this tfrecord file and do stuff

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import glob
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filenames = glob.glob('*.tfrecords')
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
   filenames)
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
feature_set = { 'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
           }

features = tf.parse_single_example( serialized_example, features= feature_set )
label = features['label']

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run([image,label])
```

Here's an example for MNIST in [tensorflow/examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py)

Cheers!